# List of available VS2010 hotfixes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hotfix

With the regularity of VS2010 crashes increasing as I use it, I was looking for a list of hotfixes.  [This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/patch-available-for-cut-or-copy-displaying-insufficient-memory-error-in-vs-2010/) says there is no official list, so let's make one (RTM only please).

Or is this page sufficient instead: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads ?

- Insufficient Memory Error on Cut or Copy

  - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29729&wa=wsignin1.0
- Enable Managed Incremental Build for Visual C++ projects (wasn't available for configuration previously)

  - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB982721

Comment: Figured I'd mention them any I install.  Fix the Find/Replace dialog growing uncontrollably - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30518&wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 6):

I have found the following to be available.
Feel free to *update* and **edit** this list where required!

**VS 2008 SP1:**

- KB945140 - VS 2008 SP1
- KB972222 - security update
- KB973675 - ATL security update
- KB2251487 - xml editor security update
- KB2538241 - security update
- KB2669970 - security update
- KB2938806 - macros fix

**VS 2010 SP1:**

- KB983509 - VS 2010 SP1
- KB2529927 - msi setup project issue
- KB2548139 - IDE crash for webpage design view
- KB2549864 - report viewer
- KB2565057 - VC runtime and redist msm
- KB2635973 - crash in localized IDE
- KB2645410 - AppenvStub security issue
- KB2736182 - unit test issues
- KB2890573 - coded UI test issues
- KB2938807 - macros broken
- KB3002340 - unexpected dialog box
- KB2504637 - fix for vs 2010 multi targeting pack dotnet 4

**VS 2012 SP5:**

- KB2707250 - VS 2012 update 5
- KB2781514 - stability update
- KB3002339 - fix for .net framework 4.5.3

**VS 2015 SP3:**

- KB3022398 - VS 2015 update 3
- KB3165756 - cumulative update