# Recommended Updates and Patches for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, patch

It's November 2010 and I just installed Visual Studio 2010 on a new dev box and am ready to get jiggy with ASP.NET 4.0 and all the new web goodness from Redmond.

Will running Windows + Microsoft Update on the system get me where I need to be patch and security wise for VS2010? Or do I need to hunt down additional patches and install them to get it leveled up to where it's as stable as can be? ie: patches like:

[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/patch-available-for-the-growing-find-and-replace-dialog/)

and

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=29729

I'd love a link to an up-to-date zero to hero posting enumerating steps to get VS2010 all patched up and ready to roll.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at this: [List of available VS2010 hotfixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375407/list-of-available-vs2010-hotfixes)

It also looks like they aren't planning on doing a roll-up any time soon: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vseditor/thread/acfb1dae-df17-4c99-8ac9-391c2a8b36cc

Answer (score 1):

[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hotfixes-available-for-scrolling-context-menu-problem/)

That was annoying.
​​​​​​​